# Inserting INTO a Table with VARRAY data type column using python

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, python-oracledb

I have a table that contains a varray data type column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE updated_cols_type AS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2(50);

CREATE TABLE "AUDIT" 
   ("TABLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "USER_NAME" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "APP_USER_NAME" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "UPDATED_COLS" "UPDATED_COLS_TYPE"
   )
```

I am trying to insert data into this table using python-oracledb function executemany()

Below are the some details

```
sql_for_audit_update = "insert into audit
                            (table_name, user_name, app_user_name, updated_cols)
                            values (:1, :2, :3, :4)"

cur.executemany(sql_for_audit_update, (tname, uname, appuname, updated_cols))
```

updated_cols variable is a list variable (for example ['col_a','col_b'])

I get the following error when I run this piece of code

"oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: ORA-01484: arrays can only be bound to PL/SQL statements"

There is no documentation available in [official documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html) regarding inserting data into variable arrays.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, VARRAY and PL/SQL index by tables do not allow for any conversion between each other and only PL/SQL index by tables allow for generic type matching. VARRAY must be handled with a specific type. So you have to do the following:

```py
typ = conn.gettype("UPDATED_COLS_TYPE")
obj = typ.newobject()
obj.extend(['String 1', 'String 2', 'String 3'])
```

Then the value in `obj` can be passed as a bind value to the `UPDATED_COLS` column.

Comment: Thank you so much Anthony! The code snippet you gave worked perfectly!! Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Anthony, not sure if you know the answer to this, but inserting into a varray only works when using cursor.execute(). If I use cursor.executemany() function, with multiple rows of data, I get the error "oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPY-4010: a bind variable replacement value for placeholder ":1" was not provided". However, cursor.executemany() works with a single row! If you have any observations about this, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: It should work just fine with cursor.executemany() but if you have a test case that demonstrates otherwise, please log an issue on the python-oracledb GitHub site!

Comment: That site is https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues